# left outer join by comparing 2 files

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have 2 files as shown below:

```
success.txt
amar
akbar
anthony
john
jill
tom

fail.txt
anthony
tom
```

I want to remove the records from sucess.txt those matches with fail.txt

```
Expected output:
amar
akbar
john
jill
```

Comment: Is the output order of important, or can they be sorted?

Comment: They can be sorted. But it is better to keep the same order. I am not sure if this will work # cat success.txt | grep -v -f fail.txt

Comment: That will work, except that some extra names might be removed - e.g. 'tom' will match 'tomas'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* a [Posix-standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#POSIX.2) **join(1)** program in all modern Unix systems, [see *man join.*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join)

```
$ join -v1 success.txt fail.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`fgrep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) - if available - as you're using fixed strings it should be more efficient.

```
fgrep -v -x -f fail.txt success.txt
```

You need the `-x` option to ensure only whole lines are matched, otherwise fails like `tom` will match successes like `tomas`.

Answer (score 2):

awk one-liner: also keep the original order

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next;}!($0 in a)' fail.txt success.txt
```